# Visual Studio Installation not found by installer despite the right path being used

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I want to add features to my Visual Studio installation. Visual Studio still runs and I can use it with the exception of C++ projects. I tried menu bar - tools - add feature and I tried doing so via the control panel - add remove programs. The installation directory Visual Studio has is correct and I can see many directories there. There does not seem to be a 'repair' option in the control panel for this application in my case.

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I reinstalled Visual Studio which resolved the issue.